How can I whitelist connections from my Lightsail Container Instance to my MsSQL RDS database
I have both a Ubuntu based Instance/VM as well as a Ubuntu based container service running in Lightsail currently. Additionally I have a MsSQL RDS instance running in AWS in the same region in the regions default VPC.
I managed to successfully activate VPC peering in my Lightsail account. Additionally I have  whitelisted connections from any Lightsail services by allowing connections from the full 172.26.0.0/16 IP range that Lightsail services use. This has allowed me to connect from my regular Instance/VM without issues. However from my Lighstail Container Service attempts to connect to the database timeout.
How can I get this working?

I now also whitelisted Lightsails IPv6 IP range 2600:1f18:10ff:4c00::/56 as well just in case its connecting via IPv6 and this did not help as well

It turns out that my RDS MsSQL was not in the region's default VPC like I thought. Once I moved the instance to the correct VPC everything started working properly.

Make sure to verify that the routes are correctly set up in the subnet where your RDS instance is located. To do this:
•   Go to the VPC settings in your AWS Console.
•   Navigate to Subnets and select the subnet where your RDS instance is located.
•   Click on Route Tables.
There should be a route similar to this:
•   Destination: 172.26.0.0/16
•   Target: pcx-******** (your VPC peering connection).
For some reason, when a peering connection is created, it doesn’t automatically add routes for subnets associated with an Internet Gateway (if that’s your case). You’ll need to manually add the route to enable communication.

Thanks, with your help I figured out that contrary to what I thought the RDS instance was not connected to the regions default VPC. Once I switched the RDS database to the correct VPC everything started working correctly
